# The caret changes to default when resizing console (windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, caret

I am trying to hide the caret in console, in C++ (or C as well, same thing), but when I maximize the window, the caret reappears. Is there any solution to this other than just hiding it every time the window size is changed, or doing it after every specific event?

The function I'm using:

```
void ShowConsoleCursor (const bool flag)
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo;

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = flag;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
}
```

**EDIT:** I'm also thinking that I could create a separate thread that hides the caret every **x** milliseconds. Would that be a viable option? I'm doing this for a personal project by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a thread to handle the [`WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/window-buffer-size-record-str) like:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE hStdin;
void ShowConsoleCursor(const bool flag)
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursorInfo;

    GetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
    cursorInfo.bVisible = false;
    SetConsoleCursorInfo(out, &cursorInfo);
}
VOID ErrorExit(LPCSTR str)
{
    printf("%s\n",str);
    exit(0);
}

VOID ResizeEventProc(WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD wbsr)
{
    printf("Resize event\n");
    printf("Console screen buffer is %d columns by %d rows.\n", wbsr.dwSize.X, wbsr.dwSize.Y);
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);
}
DWORD WINAPI Thread(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    DWORD cNumRead, i;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        ErrorExit("GetStdHandle");

    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for the events.

        if (!ReadConsoleInput(
            hStdin,      // input buffer handle
            irInBuf,     // buffer to read into
            128,         // size of read buffer
            &cNumRead)) // number of records read
            ErrorExit("ReadConsoleInput");


        for (i = 0; i < cNumRead; i++)
        {
            switch (irInBuf[i].EventType)
            {
            case WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT: // scrn buf. resizing
                ResizeEventProc(irInBuf[i].Event.WindowBufferSizeEvent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(VOID)
{
    ShowConsoleCursor(false);
    DWORD tid = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread, 0, 0, &tid);

    //To Do

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```